# PHP Symfony 2 set value of PDF field

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

Is there elegant solution to set value of PDF field with php

Exemple

```
$read = readPdfFile('pdf_file.pdf');
$array = ['param1'=> 'Foo'];
$newFile = setFromFile($read,$array);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after research i found solution :

frist you should install pdftk on your laptop

after i build a class/Service to call pdftk command line (PS the class is not finish yet but it's works)

```
class PdfFormService implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

/** @var $pdfUrl string */
private $pdfUrl;


/** @var $data array */
private $data;


/** @var  $output string */
private $outPut;


/** @var string string */
private $flatten = "";

public function __construct()
{

}

/**
 * @param $pdfUrl
 * @param array $data
 * @param null $outPut
 *
 * Init Service
 */
public function setAttribute($pdfUrl, array $data, $outPut = null)
{
    $this->pdfUrl = $pdfUrl;
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->outPut = $outPut;
}

/**
 * Rendre les champ nom modifiable après
 */
public function setFlatten()
{
    $this->flatten = ' flatten ';
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Return un fichier tmp
 * @return bool|string
 */
private function getTmpFile()
{
    return tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), gethostname());
}

/**
 * @param $fdpFile
 *
 * Execute de commande line
 */

private function execute($fdpFile)
{
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 3) == "Win") {
        $pdftk = escapeshellarg("C:/Program Files (x86)/PDFtk/bin/pdftk.exe");
        exec("$pdftk $this->pdfUrl fill_form $fdpFile output $this->outPut  $this->flatten");
    } else {
        exec("pdftk $this->pdfUrl fill_form $fdpFile output $this->outPut $this->flatten");
    }

    unlink($fdpFile);

}


    private function generateFdf($data)
    {
        // pas touche a l'indentation 
        $fdfHeader = <<< FDF
        %FDF-1.2
        1 0 obj<< /FDF<< /Fields[
FDF;
        $fdfFooter = <<< FDF
        ] >> >>
        endobj
        trailer
        <</Root 1 0 R>>
        %%EOF
FDF;
        $fdfContent = '';
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $fdfContent .= "<< /T({$key})/V({$value})>>";
        }
        $content = $fdfHeader . $fdfContent . $fdfFooter;
        $fdfFile = $this->getTmpFile();
        file_put_contents($fdfFile, $content);
        return $fdfFile;
    }


public function save($path = null)
{
    if (!is_null($path)) {
        $this->outPut = $path;
    }
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("Empty data Generate PDF");
    }

    $fdlFile = $this->generateFdf($this->data);
    if (empty($this->outPut) || empty($this->pdfUrl)) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("Url de sortie ou entrer vide ");
    }

    $this->execute($fdlFile);

    return $this;
}


public function download()
{

    $filepath = $this->outPut;
    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . uniqid(gethostname()) . '.pdf');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));

        readfile($filepath);

        exit;
    }
}



}
```

If you are in symfony

```
 $data  = ['KEY_PARAMS_IN_PDF' => 'Light yagami'];

    /** @var  $pdf PdfFormService */
    $pdf = $this->get('gdf.pdf.from.service');
    $pdf->setAttribute('modele.pdf',$data,'toto.pdf');

    $pdf->setFlatten()
        ->save()
        ->download();
```